# Chrome Extension ContextMenu: Get title %s as a string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first Chrome extension and have run into an issue. My desired functionality is that when a user right-clicks a selected word, I want the context menu that spawns to display that word as a menu item AND log the text as a string for later use. By using %s as the value for the title property, when the menu is created it will display that text. I can't seem to figure out how to capture that in a variable as well. Code below:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'wasFired': false});
    console.log("event firing");

    // begin creation of menu
    var master = chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "id": "SynoStart",
        "title": '%s',
        "contexts":["selection"]
    });
});
```

If I run a function inside contextmenu.create and log the object to the console I can dig down and parse out the title. Unfortunately it returns as %s instead of the user's selected text (code below).

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'wasFired': false});
    console.log("event firing");

    //begin creation of menu
    var master = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "SynoStart",
    "title": '%s',
    "contexts":["selection"]
    },
    function(){
        console.log(this.args[0].title); //returns "%s"
    });
});
```

If I let the callback finish and run a simply `console.log(master);` it only returns the ID as a string (in this case "SynoStart"). Running `console.log(master.title);` returns undefined. Examples below:

```
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function() {
        chrome.storage.local.set({'wasFired': false});
        console.log("event firing");

        //begin creation of menu
        var master = chrome.contextMenus.create({
            "id": "SynoStart",
            "title": '%s',
            "contexts":["selection"]
        });
        console.log(master); //returns "SynoStart"
        console.log(master.title); //returns undefined
    });
```

Is there any way to dynamically extract the title property (as a string) of this menu object at its creation?

This is my first question on SO, so please feel free to let me know how I should improve it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I can't do it either.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome documentation for [`chrome.contextMenus.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) indicates that you can specify a callback function that receives two params, the first of type OnClickData and the second of type Tab. Some current bug in their documentation is causing the description of OnClickData to be inaccessible. Fortunately, you can still read it in [Opera's documentation](http://dev.opera.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData). There you'll see that there is a `selectionText` field with description: "The text for the context selection, if any."

Note that the callback function for click events on your menu is specified as an `onclick` field of the create details. The callback function specified as the second parameter of `chrome.contextMenus.create` is just to report you if the menu item was created.

So, your code can be:

```
var master = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "SynoStart",
    "title": '%s',
    "contexts":["selection"]
    "onclick": function(onClickData, tab){
        console.log(onClickData.selectionText);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have succeeded in using OnClickData in the way you suggested, but am looking to extract the information before or at the time of the menu's creation to avoid the user having to click once in the menu to initiate and then Right-Click again to see the displayed results.

Your answer was useful in providing additional information regarding the second parameter, though, so thank you. I'm still wondering if it's possible (for the sake of knowledge) to extract and use the information that Chrome interprets from the "%s" data in the title property.

Comment: @Andymaul123 Your question was "I want the context menu that spawns to display that word as a menu item AND log the text as a string for later use". This is what this answer does. If you need to do something different, create a new question and explain clearly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: My question is at the end of my code snippets: "Is there any way to dynamically extract the title property (as a string) of this menu object at its creation?". 

The statement: _My desired functionality is that when a user right-clicks a selected word, I want the context menu that spawns to display that word as a menu item AND log the text as a string for later use_ specifies that when a user right clicks a selection of text on the page, I need the context menu to display that text and log it as a string without any additional action from user, as would be needed by using OnClick.